# Segmentation Fault using stack and frame pointer

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to implement a program that compares a pair of numbers from two different lists and storing the largest number. This must use EBP register to access the parameters.

```
        segment .bss
                ans     resb 4
                buff    resb 4
                largest resb 4
                test2   resb 1
        segment .data
                num1    db 1,2,3,4
                num2    db 5,1,7,2
msg1:      db "  "
msg_size1:             equ $-msg1

space1:  db " "
space1_size:         equ $-space1

        segment .text

        global _start

_start:
                    mov byte[test2], 0
                    mov word[largest], 0
                    mov word[ans], 0
                    mov word[buff], 0
                    mov esi, 0
                    mov bx, 0

label1:
                    cmp esi, 3
                    jg label3
                    mov ecx, [num1+esi]
                    mov edx, [num2+esi]

                    push ecx
                    push edx

                    ;;mov dword[test2], esi
                    call which_is_larger_procedure
                    add esp, 8
                    mov eax, [num2+esi]
                    mov [ans], eax

                    ;;mov esi, dword[test2]
        ;; mov [buff], esi

;;; ;   outut
        ;; mov eax, 4          ; system_write
        ;; mov ebx, 1          ; stdout
        ;; mov ecx, [ans]     ; move biggest element to accumulator
        ;; add ecx, 30h        ; convert to ascii representation
        ;; mov [buff], ecx     ; move to memory
        ;; mov ecx, buff       ; put pointer in ecx for printing
        ;; mov edx, 4          ; size, 4 bytes
        ;; int 80h             ; sytem call.

                    inc esi
                    jmp label1
label3:

exit:
                    mov eax, 1
                    mov ebx, 0
                    int 80h

which_is_larger_procedure:

;;; ;  Body
                    push ebp
                    mov ebp, esp
                    sub esp, 8

                    push eax
                    push ebx

                    mov ecx, [ebp+8]
                    mov edx, [ebp+12]

                    mov eax, [ecx]
                    mov ebx, [edx]



                     cmp al, bl
                     jg CL_g_DL
                     cmp byte[largest], bl
                     jg skip
                     mov byte[largest], bl

AL_g_BL:                        ;If AH is Larger than BL
                     cmp byte[largest], al
                     jg skip
                     mov byte[largest], al

label5:

skip:
;;; ; ;   outut
                    mov eax, 4   ; system_write
                    mov ebx, 1   ; stdout
                    mov ecx, [largest] ; move biggest element to accumulator
                    add ecx, 30h              ; convert to ascii representation
                    mov [buff], ecx    ; move to memory
                    mov ecx, buff      ; put pointer in ecx for printing
                    mov edx, 4        ; size, 4 bytes
                    int 80h           ; sytem call.



;;; ;  Outout
                     mov eax, 4  ; system_write
                     mov ebx, 1  ; stdout
                     mov ecx, msg1 ; put pointer in ecx for printing
                     int 80h      ; sytem call.


                    pop ecx
                    pop edx
                    add esp, 8
                    pop ebp
                    ret
```

Some of the code is slightly legacy from experimenting with why its segfaulting,

Was following this tutorial: [tutorial](https://wiki.skullsecurity.org/The_Stack)

Comment: Certainly you've tried running this under a debugger, no? At which instruction does the segfault occur?

Comment: I'm not aware of any debuggers that work with nasm, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: All of them. Debuggers don't care how you produced the binary executable. Any one (such as gdb) will happily disassemble anything you give it and allow you to step instruction by instruction.

Comment: Also check out edb, Evans debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was trying to figure out how to use GDB to debug it a friend who was looking at my code figured out the problem.

```
                mov eax, [ecx]
                mov ebx, [edx]
```

The problem here was that I was dereferencing registers that held actual data and not memory addresses to data, by simply removing the brackets the problem was resolved.

```
                mov eax, ecx
                mov ebx, edx
```

Is how it is supposed to be.